# Mongoose check reference id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm a newbie to mongoose and express. Tried to find an answer to my question, but no luck. I have the following schemas:

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var Project= new Schema ({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        min: 5,
        max: 255

    },

    description: {
        type: String,
        min: 5,
        max: 500

    },
    status: {
        type: String,
        min: 5,
        max: 255
    },
    priority: {
        type: String,
        min: 5,
        max: 255
    },
    progress: {
        type: String,
        min: 5,
        max: 255
    } ,
    _user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
});

module.exports= mongoose.model('Project', Project);
```

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var IssueSchema= new Schema ({

    description: {
        type: String,
        min: 5,
        max: 500,
        required: true

    },
    status: {
        type: String,
        min: 5,
        max: 255,
        default: "Open"
    },
    priority: {
        type: String,
        min: 5,
        max: 255
    },
    deadline:{
        type: Date
    },

    _project: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Project'
    }
});



module.exports= mongoose.model('Issue', IssueSchema);
```

I'm working on create Issue middleware for the route /projectId/issues and have the code

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const Issue = require ('../models/Issue');
var Project = require ('../models/Project');
const { handleError,ErrorHandler } = require('../helpers/error');

exports.createIssue = (req, res,next) => {
    Project.findById(req.params.id);
        if (req.params.id!= null) {
            console.log('Project found');
            const {description, deadline, priority, status} = req.body;
            var issue = new Issue({  
                description,
                deadline,
                status,
                priority,
                _project:req.params.id
             });
        issue.save();
        res.status(200).send("Issue created!")}
        else {
            err = new Error('Project ' + req.params.id + ' not found');
            err.status = 404;
            return next(err);
        }
    };
```

And it's not working :(  What I'm trying to achieve is to check if projecID exists before saving "issue" document. Any ideas on how to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Project.findById` accepts a callback with parameters `error` and `document`

```
Project.findById(req.params.id, (error, project) => {
  console.log(project) // project will be null if not found.
  // handle project !== null here
})
```

Comment: yay! That helped! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are checking whether or not an id was passed to params:

```
if (req.params.id!= null)
```

But this does not tell you whether there is a Project associated with that id. You need to check the return value of Project.findById(req.params.id). Some like:

```
let result = Project.findById(req.params.id)
if(!result.length) console.log('No project found")
```

In this case, I'm pretty sure the result variable will be an array however, it may also be an object so console.log(result) and see what you get. Then write you conditional statement based on that.

Also, if you want to catch any errors, you need to use a try/catch block instead of if/else.

Comment: `findById()` returns a single document and if you want to use `result` assignment, you have to `await Project.findById(req.params.id)`